# Find duplicates in array

Tags: c#, arrays, find

```
int[] array = { 10, 5, 10, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 12 };
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
    {
        if (array[i] == array[j])
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(array[i] + " repeats " + count + " times");
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

[image: Output]

I don't want to use LINQ!
My question is, how to print results only once. For example:

10 repeats 2 times
5 repeats 3 times
2 repeats 2 times
...

Thanks.

Comment: "I don't want to use LINQ! " Why not?

Comment: Tell your teacher that LINQ rocks and you don't want to think how to solve it without LINQ.

Comment: Try writing the problem out as a flow chart. Think about it logically and use the skills you will have taught in class to come up with a solution.

Comment: There is a logic behind LINQ, I want to learn algorithms, logic and only after that I will use LINQ.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how you do it without LINQ :

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();
foreach (var element in array)
{
    dictionary[element] = (dictionary.ContainsKey(element) ? dictionary[element] : 0) + 1;
}

foreach (var pair in dictionary)
{
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + " repeats " + (pair.Value - 1) + " times");
}
```

Compare it to LINQ, and you'll know why it sucks :

```
foreach (var number in array.GroupBy(x => x))
{
    Console.WriteLine(number.Key + " repeats " + (number.Count() - 1) + " times");
}
```

EDIT: changed `count` to `(count - 1)`, as OP wants repeat times, and not count.

Answer (score 4):

You can acheive what you need using Dictionary.

```
int[] array = { 10, 5, 10, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 12 };
var dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
foreach (var num in array)
{
    if (!dict.ContainsKey(num))
    {
        dict.Add(num, 0);
    }
    dict[num]++;
}

foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} repeats {1} times", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

Comment: Nice performance - `O(n)` solution - alwasy better than `n^2` :)

Comment: No, not always. This uses much more additional memory, putting values in dict is not free, ContainsKey may not be linear time, how expensive are hash collisions...

Answer (score 0):

Use dictionary:

```
var results = new Dictionary<int, int>();
...
if (array[i] == array[j])
{
     if (!results.ContainsKey(i)) results.Add(i, 0); 
     results[i]++;
}
...
//after loop
foreach (var pk in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} repeats {1} times", pk.Key, pk.Value);
}
```

But it is not optimal solution - it can be done in `O(n)` time.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] array = { 10, 5, 10, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 12 };
Dictionary<int, int> duplicateCounters = new Dictionary<int, int>();
foreach (int i in array)
    if (!duplicateCounters.ContainsKey(i))
        duplicateCounters[i] = 1;
    else
        ++duplicateCounters[i];
foreach (var item in duplicateCounters)
    if (item.Value > 1)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} repeats {1} times", item.Key, item.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine doing it yourself. You would get a blank sheet of paper and a pen. YOu would look at each number and go "do I have a count on my sheet for this number?" - no so write "10 , 1" on the sheet else replace "n, count" by "n, count + 1"

now you have a sheet that says

```
10,2
0,4
7,42
```

etc (note I did not verify these counts with your sample data )

Just convert that logic into code. Hint you need

```
Dictionary <int, int>
```

as your sheet of paper

Answer (score 0):

you could use an auxiliary data structure to keep track of the numbers that you found and how many times that number was found.

e.g.

```
Dictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
...

    if (array[i] == array[j])
    {
        if (dict.ContainsKey(array[i]))
        {
            dict[array[i]] += 1; 
        }
        else
        {
            dict.Add(array[i], 1);
        }                        
    }

...
foreach (int key in dict.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine(key + " repeats " + dict[key] + " times");
}
```

I hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] array = { 10, 5, 10, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 12 };
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
int count = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
{
    if (array[i] == array[j])
    {
        count = count + 1;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(array[i] + " repeats " + count + " times");
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

There is a reason why you see multiple console writes. You are comparing first elem (10) with all elems in array. So there is another 10 and your code detects that.
But on third pass you are comparing third elem (10) with first elem (10). Didn't you already checked for that? if `a == b`, `b == a` :)

There is second mistake in your code. `i = 0` and `j = 0`. Do you see that? You are comparing first elem with itself! Do you want what? Of course `array[0] == array[0]`, it's the same elem :)
And you are comparing each elem with itself whenever `i == j`.

You may think of your code execution as square `i*j`, where i and j are array.Length. Because `i == j`, it's called quadratic. `i*j == i*i == i^2. O(i^2)`

.

What could you do? Look at this code:

```
int[] array = { 10, 5, 10, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 12 };
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
int count = 1;
for (int j = i + 1; j < array.Length; j++)
{
    if (array[i] == array[j])
    {
        count = count + 1;
    }
}
// if (count != 1)
Console.WriteLine(array[i] + " repeats " + count + " times");
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

It look almost the same except `int j = i + 1;` With that you will never compare item to itself and you are cutting iterations in half. O(n^2/2). Basically cutting a square in a triangle. Sounds cool right? But that /2 optimization will disappear as soon as array.Length increases by 1. And our console report is still with duplicates.
There is commented if. That hack 'fixed' the report. Can you spot the error? What would report be if you change number 11 to 10?

So, this demonstrate it's impossible to write report while you are traversing an array, because you are not memorizing previous count. One option is to use hash or binary tree to commit each value in memory like suggested in other answers. That requires extra memory. Second option is to destroy/delete/null the same items, which is not cheap...

Happy learning :)

Comment: This code, skip the last element of array, cause in second loop you are starting from i+1, and it will end at array length -1, so the last element will be never checked

Comment: @sergiu.cs  array.length-1 is index of last elem in array :)

Answer (score 0):

Although the dictionary approach works great, we can also use [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-6.0) to achieve the same

```
  public static bool ContainsDuplicate(int[] nums)
    {
        var temp = new HashSet<Int32>();

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
        {
            if (temp.Contains(nums[i]))
            {
                return true;
            }
            temp.Add(nums[i]);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

From the HashSet documentation

> The HashSet class is based on the model of mathematical sets and
> provides high-performance set operations similar to accessing the keys
> of the Dictionary<TKey,TValue> or Hashtable collections. In simple
> terms, the HashSet class can be thought of as a
> Dictionary<TKey,TValue> collection without values.